# Spark failed to connect with executors

Tags: apache-spark

I have a problem when to connect with spark cluster. 
My application(driver) runs on local env and spark cluster run on cloud. If my application starts, it success to connect with master but fails to connect with executor. I think it's network problem like acl. I can't solve it.

Please help me.

This is Error logs

```html
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/14 18:57:25 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 46530@ambari004-airshow-jp2p-dev.lineinfra-dev.com
17/06/14 18:57:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
17/06/14 18:57:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
17/06/14 18:57:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
17/06/14 18:57:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/14 18:57:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: irteam,dongyoung
17/06/14 18:57:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: irteam,dongyoung
17/06/14 18:57:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/06/14 18:57:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/06/14 18:57:26 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(irteam, dongyoung); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(irteam, dongyoung); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
 at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
 at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
 ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.70.22.192:59291
 at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
 at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: /10.70.22.192:59291
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
 at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
 ... 1 more
```

`

Comment: does ping works to 10.70.22.192?

Comment: 10.70.22.192 is my local ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is user permission issue, atleast log says so.

You should start your spark job from your on-prem driver node with an user-id that has access to the cluster.

Use hdfs/spark level user to trigger your job.

Comment: i think so. How can I set user-id that has access to the cluster at my local pc ??

Comment: You should have just the same user:group as of the cluster in your system.             Try submitting the spark job in `cluster` deploy-mode. (rather than `client` mode)

Comment: How can I my app run on cluster-mode not by spark-submit script ?

Comment: You may use this:

`val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("SparkApp")
   .master("spark: //192.168.60.80:7077")
   .config("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()`